# Making Sentry report 5XX errors in multi-thread environment

Tags: django, sentry

I am using Sentry to power up exception handling logging in my app.

The issue arises in the following code snippet:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def testView(request):
    a = 1/0 # This error is reported to Sentry
    TestThread().start()
    return f_response_ok()

class TestThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        print('Test')
        a = 1/0 # but this one is not
        return True
```

Is it possible to make Sentry report errors that have occurred in parallel thread?

*And a bit off-topic:
I would appreciate if someone provides a short comment as to whether such programming pattern is obsolete (and stuff like RabbitMQ should be used instead).*

Comment: Do you expect specific exception to occur or just anything?

Comment: I've updated the topic of the question. I mean, 5XX errors - that is, anything

Comment: Perhaps you are using Django's default 500 handler instead of Sentry's one. Do you mind sharing relevant `settings.py` entries?

Comment: Well, in the main thread, errors are reported. See the updated code snippet

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan this question is kinda old, but it really seems like you want Celery or something like that. I can't imagine that spawning a thread inside of a WSGI app goes well. Raven has integration for Celery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could manually log them to sentry.

https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/#capture-an-error

Assuming you are using django

```
from raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.models import client

class TestThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        print('Test')
        try:
            a = 1/0 # error is not reported in Sentry
        except: # I would suggest putting here expected exceptions
            client.captureException()
        return True
```

Comment: This is extremely useful hint, Sardorbek. You solved one more related issue for me. Thanks !!! I will wait for a while. And unless I get more generic answer, will accept this one as solution